# WebJob Resources in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a Webjob which holds quite a lot of data in memory and can run for long periods of time. As a webjob runs as part of a service plan I can see the highest level of resource available to a service plan is 7GB of memory. Obviously this plan is shared across other things using it too like websites etc. My question is as follows, If I require that my webjob needs more memory than is available in a service plan, what are my options? Is there something else in Azure that will allow me to run my C# Console App on a scheduled basis with more resource? I am currently using the Azure Queue to trigger a continuous webjob.

Comment: I think Azure Bath has more computing resource. Iy shoud work for you. Or you can scale you webjob. Or you can use Azure function with a dynamic app service plan ?

Comment: I have been looking into Azure functions but it looks like there is a 1.5GB limit for these? @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I believe Azure Functions is exactly what you are looking for. It allows for running your custom code on a scheduled\triggered basis and can scale indefinitely "for free" in a sense that it doesn't need any manual interventions, not in a sense of money.

It also allows for easy integrations with Azure Queue, for example.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-storage/#storagequeueoutput

Comment: I already have a console app and I publish it as an Azure Webjob. How would I publish to an Azure Function?

Comment: not sur if function is the best option because it is designed to run short job not lon running process

Comment: Actually yes, I take that back, Azure Function can be used as long running process, but 1.5gb seems to be the cap for Azure functions.

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently using the Azure Queue to trigger a continuous webjob.

Since your webjob is running in continuous mode with Azure queue triggered. I think [scale out](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/) maybe help you to reduce your memory consumption. If you want to avoid wasting of resources, please try use [Auto scale](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devschool/2015/05/24/azure-how-to-auto-scale-your-web-apps-web-sites/).